# Socket reading and writing not in order

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple server program that waits for 2 clients to connect, sends the first client "1" and the second "2" to tell them who is first. then i want this kind of behavior:

client 1: writes

client 2: receives and prints

client 2: writes

client 1: receives and prints

What i'm getting is a weird behavior:

client 1: writes

client 2: writes and only *then* gets what client 1 wrote

client 1: writes and only *then* gets what client 1 wrote

and it keeps going.

[**CLIENT**](https://pastebin.com/a7r20F2D)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int clientSocket,first,readValue = 1;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    struct in_addr address;
    struct hostent *server;
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(!inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &address)){
        throw "Can't parse IP address";
    }
    server = gethostbyaddr((const void*)&address, sizeof address, AF_INET);
    if(server == NULL){
        throw "Host is unreachable";
    }
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy((char*)&serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr,
            (char*)server->h_addr, server->h_length);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(8000);

    if(connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr,
        sizeof serverAddr)){
        throw "error connecting server";
    }
    cout<< "connected to server";
    //Server tells the client if he's first or second
    memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
    read(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);
    //assigning the "first" variable
    if(!strcmp(buffer,"1")){
        first = 1;
        cout<<"I am first";
    }
    else if(!strcmp(buffer,"2")){
        first = 0;
        cout<<"I am first";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Error";
        return 0;
    }
    while (true)
    {
        memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
        if(first == 0){
            //read from server
            readValue = read(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof buffer);
            if(readValue < 1){
                throw "Error reading from socket";
            }
            cout<<buffer<<endl;
            //print it
            memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
            //write to buffer
            cin>>buffer;
            write(clientSocket,buffer,sizeof buffer);
            memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
        }
        if(first == 1){
            //write to buffer
            cin>>buffer;
            write(clientSocket,buffer,sizeof buffer);
            memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
            //read from server
            readValue = read(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof buffer);
            if(readValue < 1){
                throw "Error reading from socket";
            }
            cout<<buffer<<endl;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[**SERVER**](https://pastebin.com/bcsrGetE)

```
void GameServer::start(){
    int client1_sd, client2_sd;
    char buffer[1024];
    //clients' variables
    struct sockaddr_in client1Address, client2Address;
    socklen_t client1AddressLen, client2AddressLen;
    //cleaning buffer
    memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
    //Creating the socket
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(serverSocket == -1){
        throw "Error opening socket";
    }
    //Creating socket address variable for binding
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    //initializing it to 0's
    bzero((void *)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //Gets connections from anything
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr= INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(port);
    //binding
    if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr* )&serverAddress,
        sizeof(serverAddress)) == -1){
        throw "Error on binding";
    }
    listen(serverSocket, MAX_CONNECTED_CLIENTS);
    //If a game has ended, start a new one
    while(true){
        //start listening for clients
        cout<<"Waiting for connections"<<endl;
        //Accepting first client
        client1_sd = accept(serverSocket,
                (struct sockaddr* )&client1Address,
                 &client1AddressLen);
        cout<< "Client 1 entered!"<<endl;
        //Sending 1 to him to show him he is the first to enter
        buffer[0] = '1';
        write(client1_sd,buffer,1024);
        //Accepting second client
        client2_sd = accept(serverSocket,
                (struct sockaddr* )&client1Address,
                &client1AddressLen);
        cout<<"Client 2 entered!"<<endl;
        //Sending 2 to him to show him he is the second to enter
        buffer[0] = '2';
        write(client2_sd,buffer,1024);
        while(true){
            memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
            //taking input form client 1
            read(client1_sd, buffer, 1024);
            if(!strcmp(buffer, "End")){
                close(client1_sd);
                close(client2_sd);
                break;
            }
            cout<<buffer<<endl;
            //returning the message
            write(client2_sd, buffer, 1024);
            memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
            //taking input from client 2
            read(client2_sd, buffer, 1024);
            if(strcmp(buffer, "End") == 0){
                close(client1_sd);
                close(client2_sd);
                break;
            }
            cout<<buffer<<endl;
            //returning the message
            write(client1_sd, buffer, 1024);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to pass actual length of buffer instead of 1024 in each write statement. E.g last statement write(client1_sd, buffer, strlen(buffer)) should ideally be write(client1_sd, buffer, 1024). Also add error handling: 

On success, the number of bytes written are returned (zero indicates nothing was written). On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately

Comment: Rather than using the magic number 1024, you should use `sizeof(buffer)` or a well-named constant that is also used to size the buffer.  This way when the buffer changes size you don't have to play hunt the magic number and pray you get them all and not a 1024 that's being used for some other purpose.

Comment: Reading from sockets may not give you all the bytes you are expecting. Always check the return value. A negative return signals an error, a zero signals the socket has closed, and any other number is the number of bytes read. In this case it can be any number from 1 up to 1024. So `read(client2_sd, buffer, 1024);` may not contain all of "End", for example. It could contain "En" with the "d" in a packet that will arrive in the future. It could contain a thousand bytes of data from a previous write followed by "End". You will not know unless you check.

Comment: You're using a streaming protocol and treating it as a packet-oriented protocol. If you want packets, you need to implement them yourself on top of the stream.

Comment: 0 signals the *connection* has closed. It is still up to you to close the socket. @user4581301

Comment: TCP will always deliver data in order, and there is nothing in your question that suggests otherwise.

Comment: Yes. Bad wording on my part.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true what user4581301 wrote in his comment, your program behaves not as wanted even when write and read data are not fragmented, because:

- the server sends "1" and "2" with `write(clienti_sd,buffer,1024)`, i. e. it sends 1024 bytes;
- each client receives its number with `read(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1)`, i. e., since it's `char buffer[1024]`, it can receive only 1023 bytes;
- so, there remains 1 byte unread for the client, which the second client then receives with his next `read from server`, mistaking it for the data which would be sent after the server received from the first client, and thus the second client continues with writing early.